# Can I rectrict vim/gvim to use only tabs as line start character?

Tags: vim

I want to use only tabs without space

```
\t\t...\tdef
```

not

```
\t \tdef
```

or

```
\t\t  def
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the content. Can you fix one to match the other to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

So long as you are using `noexpandtab`, `vim` will only add spaces when 'tabbing' manually if the setting of the `softtabstop` option does not equal the `tabstop` option value.

Similarly, `vim` won't use spaces when you use the `<<` or `>>` commands if you use the same setting for `shiftwidth` as you do `tabstop`.

`vim` won't stop you from adding spaces inbetween tabs if you really try. If you want to spot these you can make occasional use of the `:set list` command or even use a syntax highlight rule to show them. (The sequence '`\t`' is usually 'wrong'.)

Comment: Instead of higlighting I what auto removing unnecessary spaces.

Comment: You mean something like: `:s/ \{8\}^I/^I^I/gc` then `:s/ \+^I/^I/gc` where `^I` is usually typed `<C-V><tab>` ?

Comment: May be is there any way to not use replace?

Comment: What do you mean? Appropriate tabstop settings will mean that vim won't automatically insert spaces; if you don't want them you won't be inserting them manually. This only leaves the possibility that you already have them. If this is the case, then logically you _have_ to replace them (somehow), how else are they going to disappear?

Comment: Ok. I copy some code from internet \s\s\s\s\sdef and paste it in vim and I want to get automaticly this "^I^Idef"
my settings ts=2 sw=2. Can I do it somehow without additional key pressing?

Comment: Not with a conventional put command, I don't believe, but you could set up a new function and keybinding to do a :put and a :retab! in one go?